# SOS game tkinter issue with checking affirming SOS has been made while staying within the bounds of the list

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter, indexing

I'm currently working on a program that allows you to select the size of a game board and then allow players to choose S or O in the goal of making SOS. I've done this with a list of buttons in the gui. Now the issue I'm stuck on is checking whether an SOS has been made while also staying within the index of my lists. The print statements in the code were to help me determine what method was being called, which was another issue that I had with depending on which button was clicked only certain if statements were being called.

```
def checksos(i, j):
 
  for i in range (len(board[j])):
    for j in range(len(board[j])):
     
        
        if board[i][j]["text"]=='S':
            
            if not  i >= len(board[j]): 
                print("h")
                if board[j][i-1]["text"] == 'O' and board[j][i-2]["text"]== 'S':
                this will execute if there is a horizontal sos
                  print("found horizontal sos")

        #check if it will go out of boundaries horizontally and vertically
            if (not i >= len(board[j])-2) and (not j >= len(board)-2):
                    print("d")
                    if board[j+1][i+1]["text"] == 'O' and board[j+2][i+2]["text"] == 'S':
                #this will execute if there is a diagonal sos
                     print("found diagonal sos")

        #check if it will go out of boundaries vertically
            if not j >= len(board)-2:
                        print("v")
                        if board[j+1][i]["text"] == 'O' and board[j+2][i]["text"] == 'S':
                #this will execute if there is a vertical sos
                         print("found vertical sos")
            if not j >= len(board)-1:
                        print("v")
                        if board[j+1][i]["text"] == 'O' and board[j+2][i]["text"] == 'S':
                #this will execute if there is a vertical sos
                         print("found vertical sos")
            if not j >= len(board):
                        print("v")
                        if board[j+1][i]["text"] == 'O' and board[j+2][i]["text"] == 'S':
                #this will execute if there is a vertical sos
                         print("found vertical sos")


        elif board[i][j]["text"]=='O':
           
           if not  i >= len(board[j])-2: 
                print("not out of bounds")
                if board[j][i-1]["text"] == 'S' and board[j][i+1]["text"]== 'S':
                #this will execute if there is a horizontal sos
                 print("found horizontal sos")

        #check if it will go out of boundaries horizontally and vertically
                if (not i >= len(board[j])-2) and (not j >= len(board)-2):
                    if board[j+1][i+1]["text"] == 'S' and board[j-1][i-1]["text"] == 'S':
                #this will execute if there is a diagonal sos
                     print("found diagonal sos")

        #check if it will go out of boundaries vertically
                    if not j >= len(board)-2:
                        if board[j+1][i]["text"] == 'S' and board[j-1][i]["text"] == 'S':
                #this will execute if there is a vertical sos
                         print("found vertical sos")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this harder than it needs to be.  In particular, I'd ask why you have each board cell be a dictionary?  Why not just store the character itself in `board[j][i]`?  That would make this a lot easier.

What I've done here is, for each row and for each column, convert the whole row or columns into a single string, then search the string for "SOS".

I also do the same for diagonals, but they're a little trickier.  If you think about the 5x5 grid I'm using here as an example, the first two strings gather up the NW-to-SE diagonals starting at (2,0), (1,0), (0,0), (0,1), and (0,2).  The second two strings gather up the NE-to-SW diagonals starting at (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (4,1), and (4,2).  That should be all diagonals.

```
def checksos(board):
    w = len(board[0])
    h = len(board)

    # Check for horizontals.

    for row in board:
        s = ''.join([cell['text'] for cell in row])
        if 'SOS' in s:
            print("found horizontal sos")

    # Check for verticals.

    for col in range(w):
        s = ''.join([board[i][col]['text'] for i in range(h)])
        if 'SOS' in s:
            print("found vertical sos")

    # Check for diagonals.  There are N-2 diagonals in each direction;
    # the outermost 2 are too short to hold SOS.

    for offset in range(0,w-2):
        # Start from the top and go SE.  If offset is 1, the
        # first string gets 1,0 then 2,1 then 3,2; the other
        # string gets 0,1 then 1,2 then 2,3.
        s1 = []
        s2 = []
        s3 = []
        s4 = []
        for i in range(0,w-offset):
            s1.append( board[i+offset][i]['text'] )
            s2.append( board[i][i+offset]['text'] )
            s3.append( board[i+offset][w-i-1]['text'] )
            s4.append( board[h-i-1][i+offset]['text'] )
        if 'SOS' in ''.join(s1) or 'SOS' in ''.join(s2) or \
           'SOS' in ''.join(s3) or 'SOS' in ''.join(s4):
            print("found diagonal sos")

board = []
for i in range(5):
    board.append( [{'text':' '} for _ in range(5)] )

board[1][1]['text'] = 'S'
board[1][2]['text'] = 'O'
board[1][3]['text'] = 'S'

board[1][4]['text'] = 'S'
board[2][4]['text'] = 'O'
board[3][4]['text'] = 'S'

board[2][2]['text'] = 'S'
board[3][3]['text'] = 'O'
board[4][4]['text'] = 'S'

checksos(board)
```

Comment: So what's currently stored within [ i ][ j ] is the buttons that are created from another button function that actually creates the game board. The Board works with any size that the user enters into an entry box. And then whenever a player selects a radio button that determines whether the players want to use an s or an o on the board they can then click any button on the board and it changes to that corresponding value. It's the only way that made sense to me in tkinter.

Comment: I see.  If I were doing it, I would have separated the board from the representation of the board.  That would, for example, let me write a console version as well as a GUI version.  But I see your point.  And please note that my code will work with arbitrary square boards; I only picked 5 out of thin air.